# Raspberry Pi as MQTT broker as well as subscriber or publisher

Tags: android, python, server, raspberry-pi, mqtt

scenario: I have a local network with some connected devices so I want to send commands from android app to Raspberry Pi which will control those connected devices by MQTT protocol so can I use Raspberry Pi as a broker as well as client (Publisher/subscriber).

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. For more information, [please see](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can run broker and client on same Raspberry Pi.

```
import time
import paho.mqtt.client as paho
#broker="broker.hivemq.com"
broker="iot.eclipse.org"
#define callback
def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    time.sleep(1)
    print("received message =",str(message.payload.decode("utf-8")))

client= paho.Client("client-001") #create client object
#client1.on_publish = on_publish #assign function to callback
#client1.connect(broker,port) #establish connection
#client1.publish("house/bulb1","on")
######Bind function to callback
client.on_message=on_message
#####
print("connecting to broker ",broker)
client.connect(broker)#connect
client.loop_start() #start loop to process received messages
print("subscribing ")
client.subscribe("house/bulb1")#subscribe
time.sleep(2)
print("publishing ")
client.publish("house/bulb1","on")#publish
time.sleep(4)
client.disconnect() #disconnect
client.loop_stop() #stop loop
```

http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/into-mqtt-python-client/
http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/python-mqtt-publish-subscribe/

Above links can direct you to solution.

Comment: This is basically a link only answer that will become useless the moment the links break.

Comment: Just adding code doesn't really improve the answer as it has no explanation as to why it's useful.